# Few queries regarding DNS record management

Tags: dns, python, dynamic-dns

I recently purchased a domain, karthikts.com(just for example but this is not the actual domain registered) and on the registrar(crazydomains.com) dashboard i could see below configs:

1. I have been alloted two name servers, ns1.crazydomains.com and ns2.crazydomains.com
2. Two A records, one "karthikts.com -> a.b.c.d" and the other "www.karthikts.com -> a.b.c.d", a.b.c.d is the IP provided by the registrar itself.

Now i want to perform below activities, so need some pointers/references to achieve them.

a]

I want to delegate dns record management for all of the sub domains under karthikts.com to another nameserver, two queries regarding this:

1. How do i delegate all the subdomains under karthikts.com to the new nameserver? What's the format of the NS record? Does it accept wildcards?
   Something like this: "*.karthikts.com => ipx"?
2. How to make a server act as a nameserver? i know that DNS server runs on UDP port 53, but how do i get one? Is there a open source DNS server software available or does it come along with OS? Also, how to feed the new DNS records for my subdomains to the DNS server?

b]

Suppose if i have two subdomains, whose A records are oxygen.karthikts.com => ip1 and carbon.karthikts.com => ip2 respectively. Is it possible to write a python program which sends dynamic DNS updates to my nameserver and switches the mapping to oxygen.karthikts.com => ip2 and carbon.karthikts.com => ip1 every half-an-hour. I am not looking for a solution for this, just want to know if it is possible and if so, are there any python libraries to make dynamic dns updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do i delegate all the subdomains under karthikts.com to the new nameserver? What's the format of the NS record?

The NS record has a single field – the server's name (but not an IP address).

For example, your current NS records are:

```
@  NS  ns1.crazydomains.com.
@  NS  ns1.crazydomains.com.
```

In some cases, additional "glue records" are needed to make the delegation work.

> Does it accept wildcards? Something like this: "*.karthikts.com => ipx"?

No, delegating wildcards [is not allowed.](https://lists.isc.org/pipermail/bind-users/2001-October/033726.html)

Instead, delegate your *entire domain*. Your registrar's website will have a separate option along the lines of "Use your own DNS servers". Using that option will fully delegate the domain (including subdomains) and will disable the registrar's web-based record editor.

> How to make a server act as a nameserver? i know that DNS server runs on UDP port 53, but how do i get one? Is there a open source DNS server software available or does it come along with OS?

There are *many.* Popular choices include NSD, PowerDNS, BIND 9, djbdns, and the one that comes with Windows Server.

DNS uses both UDP and TCP; the latter is used for large replies (to clients lacking EDNS support), for transfers between your own authoritative servers (replication), for DNS-over-TLS.

> Also, how to feed the new DNS records for my subdomains to the DNS server?

Depends on the used software. Many use a standard text format called the [zone file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zone_file). Some may have graphical tools (such as Windows Server, although it still stores data in zonefiles). Some may have support for reading data from MySQL or Postgres. Some use elder runes (djbdns).

> Is it possible to write a python program which sends dynamic DNS updates to my nameserver

Yes, depending on the used DNS server software. Many servers support updates through the standard [RFC 2136](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2136) protocol (DNS UPDATE), and some might have custom APIs for that.

For Python, you should be able to find DNS UPDATE support in any full-featured DNS module. (I keep confusing the two big DNS modules Python has, but I know at least one of them definitely supports UPDATE.)